# Jquery: How to get value from array in external text file?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to pull an error message from an external errors.txt file.

The contents of errors.txt is:

```
var data = {
'errors': [{
            "code": "9999",
            "message": {
                row: 1,
                col: 0,
                data: 'ABC',
                code: 20016,
                message: 'Invalid code.'
                }
             },
             {
              "code": "9999",
              "message": {
                  row: 1,
                  col: 0,
                  data: 'DEF!',
                  code: 20016,
                  volume: '100',
                  message: 'Invalid code.'
                  }
              }],
"data": {
    "report": null
},
"successMsg": null,
"errorMsg": null
```

}

I am trying to display the message (ie - "invalid code') and have tried the following, but no luck:

```
  jQuery.getJSON('/js/errors.txt', function (data) {
            // data is an array of objects
            $.each(data, function () {
                alert(this.errors[0].message[0].message);                
            });
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No error message, nothing in console.

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: If you open errors.txt in the browser it probably displays text with `"var data = "` which is not a valid JSON. Try to remove `"var data = "`

Comment: @SatejS I did create a plunkr here but I think I'm not pointing to the errors.txt file correctly: https://plnkr.co/edit/v20HPmhMQmmYCzQcDCDf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try as below:

**errors.txt**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "9999",
      "message": {
        "row": 1,
        "col": 0,
        "data": "ABC",
        "code": 20016,
        "message": "Invalid code."
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "9999",
      "message": {
        "row": 1,
        "col": 0,
        "data": "DEF!",
        "code": 20016,
        "volume": 100,
        "message": "Invalid code."
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "report": null
  },
  "successMsg": null,
  "errorMsg": null
}
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('errors.txt', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                alert(data.errors[0].message.message);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are traversing your JSON with  each loop try to use key & value(give your own name according to your coding choice) as parameter to it.

Please replace your inner $.each({ loop with below code

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    alert("Error Message : ", value[0].message.message);
});
```

Hope this helps to tackle the problem..